# Google in App Billing verification failed sometimes

Tags: android-pay

Our server is not able to verify signature for Google Wallet sometimes. Sometimes it works, sometimes verification failed.

We are using following guide - https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

and following Java implementation - https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/anjlab/android/iab/v3/Security.java to verify signature on server side.

I noticed that there are 2 types of orders, for example - *GPA.1391-1084-0175-28517*, orders which starts from *GPA* are verified correctly.

Verification of orders which looks like - *4781656834035199745.4951372150438022* or *4557257650215229301.5495206017032115* or simply *8120126244668862748* are always failed

Moreover I can't see failed orders ids in Google Wallet Merchant Admin screen. There are a lot of such orders from different users created in different time, it does not look like a someone is trying to hack us

Any clue is highly appreciated.